# Convert.ToBase64String() with numbers larger than 255

Tags: c#, base64

I'm using code below to convert a list of numbers to a Base64 encoded string.

The problem is that as soon as I try something over 255 I get `System.OverflowException` since it overflows the byte capacity.

What would be a good way of doing this?  There is an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) but I was just wondering if there are other ways of making this work.

```
private string DecimalToBase64(List<int> lst)
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[lst.Count];

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = Convert.ToByte(lst[i]);
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
}
```

Comment: A byte can only be 0-255 : new byte[lst.Count]

Comment: `int` is 32 bits not 8.

Comment: Right, I was aware of both of those statements.  Asked because I wasn't sure of a good workaround.  BitConverter class was the missing piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public static string DecimalToBase64(List<int> lst)
{
    var bytes = new List<byte>();
    foreach (var item in lst)
        bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(item));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes.ToArray());
}
```

Read more about bytes order [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: Ah, that BitConverter class is what I was missing

Answer (score 1):

Each `int` is 4 `byte` long.  You need to account for this in your loop.

```
private static string IntsToBase64(IEnumerable<int> lst)
{
    var arr = lst.SelectMany(i => BitConverter.GetBytes(i))
                    .ToArray();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
}

private static IEnumerable<int> Base64ToInts(string base64)
{
    var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += 4)
        yield return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, i);
}
```

.. example usage...

```
static void Main()
{
    var lst = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", lst));

    var base64 = IntsToBase64(lst);
    Console.WriteLine(base64);

    var ret = Base64ToInts(base64);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ret));
}
```

... output ...

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
AAAAAAEAAAACAAAAAwAAAAQAAAAFAAAABgAAAAcAAAAIAAAACQAAAA==
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        private string DecimalToBase64(List<int> lst)
        {
            List<byte> arr = new List<byte>();

            foreach(int number in lst )
            {
                arr.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(number));
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(arr.ToArray());
        }
```